# Can’t host a Wi-Fi network for my Apple TV

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, wifi-configuration, appletv

I need to somehow connect my Apple TV 4th Generation (Not 4K but has apps) to the internet somehow in a room that does not have an ethernet port. The problem with this is that the Wi-Fi network requires a web-based login which is not an option for my Apple TV. My only options are Eduroam (sometimes) or university Wi-Fi which both require web-based logins which an Apple TV can’t do.

I have been trying to activate the internet sharing settings from my MacBook Pro, however I can’t even get the shared network to be visible to my iPhone.

Here is how I set up my current settings:
[image]

Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: You can only share the connection if your existing connection is via ethernet cable, not wifi

Answer (score 1):

So here is the workaround I found. Turns out you cant host and receive wifi at the same time. So what I did is shared my Wifi connection through all connections. I then plugged in a USB-C to Ethernet converter and connected that Ethernet cable to the Apple TV.

That somehow worked!